# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured ,The included URLconf 'simplesocial.urls' does not appear

Tags: url-pattern

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'simplesocial.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you
see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.